# File Path and Root issues

Tags: asp.net

So I have my the path to my website code as follows:

C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/my published website code from VS2012 - on my website I get an attachment and I want to save it to the following path C:/folder4

when I try the following code: file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../../folder4/") + filename); it says that I am going past the root.  Can someone explain to me what is going on and if and how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[Server.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to get the path in relation to the server root.  Since your trying to save it outside the server virtual directory, you could probably just hardcode the file.

```
file.SaveAs(@"C:/folder4/" + filename);
```

It might not work depending on your IIS worker pool permissions.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if that will work regardless of permissions, but I am sure its probably not a good idea to save files outside of the servers virtual directory

Answer (score 0):

file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("folder4/") + filename); 
Because I cannot see your folders structure I would reccomend setting a breakpoint after Server.MapPath() to see the full URI Path to determin your next steps since it says you are past root you may have one to many "../" before your string.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx):

> you cannot specify a path outside of the Web application

which is exactly what you are trying to do. If you interpret "the root" to be the root folder of your application, that is even what the error message is telling you.

Either

1. use an absolute path or
2. store your data beneath the application folder
3. use MapPath("~/") to get the current directory and build a relative path from that (in essence, you just move the "../.." outside the call to MapPath)

I would probably recommend going with 2. as it will give less headaches wrt. permissions and multiple sites hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

[`Server.MapPath(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) tries to return a physical ("real") directory for the virtual or relative path you give it. And since a virtual directory can't be located "over" the root in that sense, what you're trying to do makes no sense. You can go from `domain.com/somefolder` to `domain.com/`, but you can't really go any farther back.

You could instead use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`as the starting point to find your folder, and apart from that just use `SaveAs(..)` as you're already doing.